# Why can't I read a SQL Server database table using a Windows group for Windows authentication?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, active-directory, windows-authentication

My goal is to provide any user who is a member of the Windows group `TestDbAccess` read access to `[Test].[dbo].[Persons]` through a C# application program.

**Problem**

- When I login to computer `C2.foo.gov` using a `domain admin account` and execute the program (see below), the program reads the database and displays the one record in the grid as expected (so I know the code is OK).
- When I login to computer `C2.foo.gov` using the `ssmith@foo.gov` account and execute the program, I get a SQL Server error `Login failed for user 'foo\ssmith'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: xxx.xx.xx.xxx]`. (Error is in `SQL Server` error log)

Why can't I read my SQL Server database table using a Windows group for Windows authentication?

**Here is what I have:**

- All computers, users, and groups are members of the domain foo.gov
- The domain is in a non-connected enclave. All firewalls are down.
- SQL Server (default instance) is installed on computer `C1.foo.gov`. Has database `Test` with table `[dbo].[persons]`. `[Test].[dbo].[Persons]` has one record. The database was created using a domain admin account that has `Server Roles` `public` and `sysadmin`. Has `User Mapping` of `db_owner` and `public` to the `Test` database.
- SQL Server (default instance) has security login foo\TestDbAccess. `Server Role` is `public`. `User mapping` is `db_datareader` and `public` for database `Test`, `user` = `foo\TestDbAccess`, `default schema` = `dbo`. Status: `Permission to connect to database engine=Grant`. `Login=Enabled`
- User `ssmith@foo.gov` is present in `Active Directory Users and Computers`
- Group `TestDbAccess` is present in `Active Directory Users and Computers`. Scope is `Global`. Type is `Security`
- `ssmith@foo.gov` is a member of `TestDbAccess`

**Code is as follows.**

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DbConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=C1;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;Connection Timeout=10"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**DatabaseAccess class**

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DbAccessWindowsGroups
{
    public static class DatabaseAccess
    {
        internal static DataTable GetData()
        {
            DataTable dataTable_TableList = new DataTable
            {
                TableName = "test"
            };

            try
            {

                using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnectionString"].ToString()))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
                    {

                        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
                        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1000 [Test].[dbo].[Persons].[iuid], [Test].[dbo].[Persons].[Name] FROM [Test].[dbo].[Persons]";
                        sqlConnection.Open();

                        SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        dataTable_TableList.Load(sqlDataReader);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }

            return dataTable_TableList;
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1 class**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DbAccessWindowsGroups
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                DataTable dataTable = DatabaseAccess.GetData();
                bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Program._DisplayMessage("Error", ex, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your details are VERY thorough.  Thanks!
Please confirm that ssmith is in domain FOO, and is enabled as a login, and then that ssmith is in the group foo\testdbaccess.  The error indicates that the user has no access.

Then what do you see (do NOT post the SID) when you run in master: "select * from sys.syslogins where [loginname] = 'foo\testdbaccess';"

Then change to the test database and let me know what you see for "select * from sys.database_principals where [name] = 'foo\testdbaccess';"

That should help us figure this out.

Comment: What difference 16 hours makes. After I posted my question on 7/16, I needed to install Windows updates on C1. I did so, restarted C1, then went home. When I came back this morning, I started to gather the answers to your questions, but then decided to retry running my program on computer C2 using the `ssmith@foo.gov` login. It worked. So, I have to assume restarting computer C1 and/or letting enough time pass for my `Active Directory` changes (adding the group `TestDbAccess` to `A.D.` and `SQL Server`) to propagate did the trick? Thoughts?

Comment: Makes sense.  Please post the answer as an answer and mark it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, my code as shown works. After I posted my question on 7/16, I needed to install Windows updates on computer C1. I did so, restarted C1, then went home. When I came back the next morning, I decided to retry running my program on computer C2 using the ssmith@foo.gov login. It worked. So, I have to assume restarting computer C1 and/or letting enough time pass for my Active Directory changes (adding the group TestDbAccess to A.D. and SQL Server) to propagate did the trick.